# GWT maven build eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gwt

I had a GWT app, and I wanted to automate its build and deploy system, since I do it manually. But I did not find a way how to build the app from command line, so it can than be automated. I had to click the Google button, then compile GWT project and then click Compile.

I found out that it is possible to create a GWT maven project and that it should then be possible to compile my project from commandline with mvn gwt:compile.

So I created a new project using this [plugin](http://gwt-plugins.github.io/documentation/gwt-eclipse-plugin/maven/Maven.html). Copied my sources from the old project to this new one.

Now the structure is like this:
/src
---/main
------/java -> here are all my sources including my Project.gwt.xml file.
------/webapp
---/test
pom.xml

Now I have 2 problems.
 1. I thought that I add dependencies to the pom.xml, and then when I build the app, it will create the jars and I can use those libraries in my GWT app. I guess 'mvn clean install' should do this, but so far I'm getting compile errors.
2. I did not get mvn clean install to work, so I added all the jars manually again... And then yes! I was able to build the app using the plugin GWT button! So I was thinking that now I can use 'mvn gwt:compile', but it fails with:

> Unable to find: "com/company/project/Project.gwt.xml" on your classpath; could be a typo, or maybe you forgot to include a classpath entry for source?

**EDIT:**
So I fixed my `<moduleName>` element in pom.xml, so now it finds the Project.gwt.xml. I'm trying to run:

```
mvn clean install gwt:compile
```

But I am getting compile errors. I think, it tries to build my project without the actual dependecies because it tells few classes don't exist, but those classes are part of an external library. (specifically [this](https://github.com/TDesjardins/gwt-ol3) one). But I have it in the dependencies, so I don't know what more to do.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.tdesjardins</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-ol3</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
  </dependency>
```

Also in eclipse I had to manually add the jars to my project, so that was why it worked there and not in the command line. So I would also like to ask how to tell eclipse to get those jars and include them to the project, because otherwise eclipse is missing those dependencies and displays many errors.

Comment: Regarding `.gwt.xml` not being found, check the answer here as I suspect you have the same problem (i.e. unlike eclipse, maven does not pick up anything other than `java` files from `src/main/java`). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45280410/maven-doesnt-add-gwt-xml-file-to-target-floder/45281134?noredirect=1#comment77525921_45281134

Comment: Which gwt maven plugin are you using? net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin or org.codehaus.mojo:gwt-maven-plugin?

Comment: net.ltgt.gwt.maven:gwt-maven-plugin:1.0-rc-6, but I will now edit my question, I'm starting to understand where the problem is.

Comment: Hi Zdeněk. We don't put answers in question posts here, so I've rolled this back one edit. If there is something in your final edit that you think should be in your answer, the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45371405/revisions) will have it.

Comment: ok, thanks, I think it's ok now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I had a problem with `<moduleName>` in my `pom.xml` was missing com.company.project prefix before the actual module name.

Then I had errors in my Java files, which was caused by RELEASE version of [GWT-OpenLayers 3](https://github.com/TDesjardins/gwt-ol3) library missing some of the features that I previously used by building the JAR from the GitHub repository.